# Can I say that people "suffer the famine"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

Is the usage of **suffer the famine** in the following sentence correct?

> - Most of the people who live in Ghana **suffer the famine**

Comment: My vote is yes, it's correct. But let others come with their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the people who live in Ghana suffer the famine.

This doesn't sound natural. First, you use the preposition "from" when some disease, adversity or unpleasant situation happens over a period of time. If something unpleasant happens quickly you don't need to use the "from", for example, I suffered a loss, he suffered a heart attack, etc.

Second, we don't need to use the definite article "the" here.  We say "he is suffering from malaria, they are suffering from hunger, etc.

So the correct sentence is as follows:

Most of the people who live in Ghana suffer from famine.

Comment: *I have never **suffered the famine** when I was in Somalia for 4 years? **Also** The Chinese suffered the famine and millions died.* -your opinion on this, please

Comment: @Maulik, both examples are seem to be correct because you referring to a specific famine.

Comment: Khan, yes; so, he's talking about *the* particular famine in Ghana... :)

Comment: Actually, the Google book returns seem to indicate 'suffer the famine' is a valid phrase in BrE, or maybe certain forms of BrE. Therefore I withdraw my earlier comments. But I  now have to withdraw my support for this answer also. I can say that in AmE, it is not a usage I have ever heard.

Comment: CarSmack/Maulik, we are referring to a prevailing situation from which people are continuously or regularly suffering. So it's correct to say "most of the people who live in Ghana suffer from famine. I think you  need to be  careful when you downvote. "Some parts of the world suffer regularly from famine (The Free Dictionary).

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/famine

Comment: CarSmack/Maulik, sorry, I should should not have said that I think you need to be careful when you downvote.